# Arrows, coordinates and labels

Tags: labels, tikz-arrows, coordinates

Please, consider the MWE below.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,
               tikz,
               preview]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
LM/.style = {
    very thin,
    {Bar[width=3.4mm]Straight Barb[]}-%
    {Straight Barb[]Bar[width=3.4mm]}
            },
every pin/.style = {
    inner sep=1pt, align=center, text=teal!20!black,
    font=\footnotesize\sffamily,
    pin edge={{Straight Barb[]}-, solid, black}
                    },
                    ]
\draw[LM] (0,0) -- node[pin=right:text] {}              + (0,0.5);
\draw[LM] (0,1) -- node[coordinate,pin=right:text] {}   + (0,0.5);
\draw[LM] (0,2) -- coordinate[pin=right:text] (a)       + (0,0.5);
\draw[LM] (0,3) -- node[inner sep=0pt,pin=right:text] {}+ (0,0.5);

\draw[LM] (2,0) -- node[pin=above:text] {}              + (0.5,0);
\draw[LM] (3,0) -- node[coordinate,pin=above:text] {}   + (0.5,0);
\draw[LM] (4,0) -- coordinate[pin=above:text] (a)       + (0.5,0);

\draw[<->]  (2,1) -- node[pin=above:text] {}              + (0.5,0);
\draw[<->]  (3,1) -- node[coordinate,pin=above:text] {}   + (0.5,0);
\draw[<->]  (4,1) -- coordinate[pin=above:text] (a)       + (0.5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Why arrows are deform when in node is present option `coordinate` or instead node is used coordinate with `pin` option?

Comment: So far I understood that coordinate is shape with zero size, i.e. all node coordinates is merged into shape "center" coordinate. But why this damage arrows layout? I expected that size of shape should not have influence on arrows.

Comment: Coordinate is placed in expected (advertised) position, however, arrow on which lie coordinate, is damaged, as you can see from picture in my question.

Comment: Did you ever report this at https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/?source=navbar? I mean, it looks like something wrong happens, so could be a bug as you say yourself.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. No, I didn't. I was not sure, if my suspicion is righteous or my understanding, how this should work, is wrong. Also I don't know, is some CVS release of TikZ already solved this.

Comment: Are there CVS releases nowadays? I think you should report it though. You can even shorten the example to `\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[<->]  (1,1) -- node[pin=above:A] {}              + (0.5,0);
\draw[<->]  (2,1) -- coordinate[pin=above:B] (a)       + (0.5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}` if needed.

Comment: @TorbjørnT., now I try to report bug, but I have troubles, how to do this (this will be my first bug report). I can't find how to add my report to the list. Should I be authorized for this? I will ask for guidance in chat room.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us fix the notation.

`\draw[<->](A)--node[pin=Dpin]{Conline}(B);`
[image]

Ti*k*Z will

- process the line `(A)--(B)`, push it into the buffer;
- create the node `Conline`;
- create the node `Dpin`;
- process the line `(Conline)edge(Dpin)`, draw it immediately;

  - `(A)--(B)` is still in the buffer;
- add arrows to the last subpath in the buffer;

  - so `(A)<->(B)` is drawn.

In the scenario above `edge` is handled separately so Ti*k*Z does append arrows to the right subpath.

If `Conline` happens to be a `coordinate`, then Ti*k*Z will

- process the line `(A)--(B)`, push it into buffer;
- create the coordinate `Conline`;
- create the node `Dpin`;
- process the line `(Conline)edge(Dpin)`, draw it immediately;

  - `(Conline)` fires a `moveto` token;
  - now the buffer becomes `(A)--(B) (Conline)`;
- add arrows to the last subspath in the buffer;

  - so `(A)--(B) (Conline)^` is drawn.

Here `^` indicates that Ti*k*Z is trying to append arrows to a subspath consisting of a single point. Everytime it does so the arrow is always pointing upward.

---

In order to prevent a `coordinate` from firing a `moveto` token, you can sqap the order of `(Conline)` and `(Dpin)`. That is,

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\makeatletter
\long\def\tikz@@parse@pin@nonactive[#1]#2:#3:\pgf@nil{%
  \tikzset{%
    append after command = {%
      \bgroup
        [current point is local = true]
        \pgfextra{\let\tikz@save@last@node=\tikzlastnode\tikz@node@is@a@labelfalse}%
        node [every pin,
              tikz@label@angle = #2,
              anchor=@auto,
              #1,
              append after command = {%
                (\tikzlastnode)               %%%% swap this node
                edge [every pin edge,
                      tikz@pre@pin@edge,
                      tikz@pin@options] 
                (\tikz@save@last@node)},      %%%% with this node
              tikz@label@post = \tikz@pin@distance,
              tikz@pin@post] {#3}
      \egroup}}}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
LM/.style = {
    very thin,
    {Bar[width=3.4mm]Straight Barb[]}-%
    {Straight Barb[]Bar[width=3.4mm]}
            },
every pin/.style = {
    inner sep=1pt, align=center, text=teal!20!black,
    font=\footnotesize\sffamily,
    pin edge={{Straight Barb[]}-, solid, black}
                    },
                    ]
\draw[LM] (0,0) -- node[pin=right:text] {}              + (0,0.5);
\draw[LM] (0,1) -- node[coordinate,pin=right:text] {}   + (0,0.5);
\draw[LM] (0,2) -- coordinate[pin=right:text] (a)       + (0,0.5);
\draw[LM] (0,3) -- node[inner sep=0pt,pin=right:text] {}+ (0,0.5);

\draw[LM] (2,0) -- node[pin=above:text] {}              + (0.5,0);
\draw[LM] (3,0) -- node[coordinate,pin=above:text] {}   + (0.5,0);
\draw[LM] (4,0) -- coordinate[pin=above:text] (a)       + (0.5,0);

\draw[<->]  (2,1) -- node[pin=above:text] {}              + (0.5,0);
\draw[<->]  (3,1) -- node[coordinate,pin=above:text] {}   + (0.5,0);
\draw[<->]  (4,1) -- coordinate[pin=above:text] (a)       + (0.5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course this means that now `pin edge={->}` is pointing to `Conline`. This is definitely not backward-compatible. But I believe that changing the behavior of a `coordinate` is even more dangerous.

Comment: sorry, i didn't notice your answer before. thank you for nice explanation, that is going on in drawing of "simple" edge (arrow) label. it is somehow unexpected that handling of coordinates is so different from nodes. from my perspective this features doesn't consider all possible use of coordinates.